# list applications deployed on glassfish from jsf application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have three JSF apps working on glassfish 3.1 opensource edition. One of them is supposed to be monitor app. I need to list deployed applications with their statuses and provide functionality of disabling and enabling them.
I know, that there is sth like GlassFish API and I've found some samples, but it's not clear to me and I can't figure out how to use it.
Can You please provide me some more detailed tutorial/example? I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the RESTful API?  Here is an example of listing applications on the DAS:
http://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/list-applications

Sample blog:

http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2010/08/glassfish-administration-the-rest-of-the-story/

Documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gjipx.html

Hope this helps.