# How to list dynamically the available web applications in Glassfish domain?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

We have an internal Glassfish 3.1 server where we have Jenkins deploy war-artifacts directly without any additional configuration.

This results in numerous rather verbose URL's like

`http://xxx:5280/xxx_YYYY-52.20120824.0-SNAPSHOT/`

and I would like to write a small ROOT.war (binding to "/") which simply lists all URL's in the current domain - preferably along with the `<web-app><description>....` field.

This only needs to work with Glassfish.  Is there a simple Glassfish API providing the information I need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175586/list-applications-deployed-on-glassfish-from-jsf-application is this something?

Comment: @AkselWillgert it looks like these access the DAS over the network.  I was wondering if I could get to this information directly by asking the container from the "inside", but if that is impossible it is the way we must go.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse domain.xml. There is information about deployed apps, context root ... smth like this

```
<application context-root="/permit-1.0" location="${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/permit-1.0/" name="permit-1.0" object-type="user">
      <property name="org.glassfish.ejb.container.application_unique_id" value="88379353331728384" />
      <property name="defaultAppName" value="permit-1.0" />
      <module name="permit-1.0">
        <engine sniffer="ejb" />
        <engine sniffer="security" />
        <engine sniffer="web" />
      </module>
    </application>
```

Comment: The various war artifacts are independently deployed from each other and from this one I'd like to write.  In other words, there is not a domain.xml directly accessible by me.

Comment: You could set the path to domain.xml as a Glassfish system property, then your app can access that property to open the file.